# Gradle initialization script for specific projects

Tags: gradle

I need to specify local publishing for certain projects with gradle, but not all.

Something like [`allprojects`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#allprojects(org.gradle.api.Action)) in init.gradle, similar to

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url 'http://nexus.myintranet.local/content/repositories/snapshots'
                credentials {
                    username 'myusername'
                    password 'mypassword'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose I have `/home/ed/xthirdparty` and `/home/ed/ythirdparty`.  How can I apply this configuration to just those two projects **without editing their build.gradle files**?  Is my only recourse to use `-I` or `--init-script`?  Or can I use a method like `allprojects` that can distinguish a project by path or another property?

Comment: Do you mean two *projects* (belonging to the same build) or two *builds*? `allprojects` configures all projects of a build (each build if you put it into `~/.gradle/init.gradle`).

Comment: I mean two builds that are unrelated. In other words, I'm looking for something like `allprojects` that can identify a particular build.

Comment: You can check `rootProject.name` in an if-statement, although it's not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  In addition, I found [`rootDir`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:rootDir), which is unique.  Could you post an answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the above comments by Peter Niederwieser, I was able to specify alternative  publishing for some projects, based on their location on the machine:

```groovy
allprojects {
    def thirdparty = [ '/home/ed/xthirdparty', '/home/ed/ythirdparty' ]
    if (rootDir.path in thirdparty) {
        apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
        publishing {
            repositories {
                maven {
                    url 'http://nexus.myintranet.local/content/repositories/snapshots'
                    credentials {
                        username 'myusername'
                        password 'mypassword'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```